# Why Reloading VSCode for changing profiles in remote but not in local?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-code-server

In the context of Visual Studio Code (VSCode) usage, a distinction arises between local and remote environments, like WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) or GitHub Codespaces, regarding profile changes. When working locally, profile modifications do not prompt a reload dialog, while in a remote environment, this dialogue appears. This disparity arises due to the underlying operational variances.

In a local setup, VSCode interacts directly with your machine's file system and settings. Consequently, altering profiles can be implemented smoothly without disrupting your workflow. VSCode achieves this by tightly integrating with the local environment, avoiding the need for a complete application restart.

Conversely, in remote setups such as WSL or GitHub Codespaces, VSCode operates on a remote server or container. Profile or setting changes often entail adjustments to the remote environment's configurations. To ensure consistent application of these modifications, VSCode necessitates a reload. This restart aligns the local VSCode client with the remote development environment, ensuring that profile changes made remotely are accurately reflected in your VSCode instance. Despite appearing as an inconvenience, this reload is essential for seamless collaboration with remote development environments, maintaining synchronization, and preserving a consistent coding experience.